# Vuejs bootstrap b-table data not loading/updating

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have an object in Vue that contains a string key for each user and a list (of courses) as the values that I would like to use to populate a b-table.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this so that the items in the table are reactive, ie the table updates as the data in the userCourses variable updates.
A simplified version of the code is shown below:

```html
<div v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user">
    <b-table :items="userCourses[user]" :fields="courseFields"></b-table>
</div>
```

```js
userCourses: {
  'userOne': [...],
  'userTwo': [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Improved example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      users: ["userOne", "userTwo"],
      userCourses: {
        userOne: [{ c: "Java" }, { c: "PHP" }, { c: "C#" }],
        userTwo: [{ c: "English" }, { c: "Polish" }, { c: "Spanish" }]
      },
      fields: [{ key: "c", label: "Course" }],
      course: "example"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addCourse() {
      this.userCourses[this.selectedUser].push({ c: this.course });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedUser: {
      get() {
        return this.user || this.users[0];
      },
      set(v) {
        this.user = v;
      }
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-radio v-for="user in users" v-model="selectedUser" name="selected-user" :key="'u-'+user" :value="user">{{user}}</b-form-radio>
  <b-form-input v-model="course" placeholder="Course name"></b-form-input>
  <b-button @click="addCourse">Add</b-button>
  <div v-for="(courses, user) in userCourses" :key="'c-'+user">
    <strong>{{user}}</strong>
    <b-table :items="courses" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Previous example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      users: ["userOne", "userTwo"],
      selectedUser: "userOne",
      courseName: "example",
      userCourses: {
        userOne: [{c: "A"}, {c: "B"}, {c: "C"}],
        userTwo: [{c: "X"}, {c: "Y"}, {c: "Z"}]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addCourse() {
      this.userCourses[this.selectedUser].push({
        c: this.courseName
      });
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-radio v-for="user in users" v-model="selectedUser" name="selected-user" :value="user">{{user}}</b-form-radio>
  <b-form-input v-model="courseName" placeholder="Course name"></b-form-input>
  <b-button @click="addCourse">Add</b-button>
  <div v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user">
    <b-table :items="userCourses[user]"></b-table>
  </div>
</div>
```